# Take input from textbox and redirect with that text to perform a google search

Tags: javascript, html

Hey everyone i am trying to solve the following question

Using form, make a page in HTML where the user can enter a keyword and click on the “Search” button and then that keyword is searched on google.

But till now have no luck in figuring out how to redirect with the i/p from my textbox in form
here is the code

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>What is PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function showDetails()
 {
    var a = document.getElementById('sea');
    window.location = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+ a;
 }
 </script>

 <img src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjN2I-drPLfAhVBrY8KHUBlCwMQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.froala.com%2Fwysiwyg-editor%2Fdocs%2Fserver%2Fphp%2Fimage-upload&psig=AOvVaw2Rv-5CgPx3gJo5_dzi6XFo&ust=1547729604931087" width="25%" height="25%">
 </img>
 <p>Php is amazing<br>Php is not cool</p>
 <button onmouseover="alert('I Love HTML too!')">I Love HTML</button>
 <br>
 <br>
 <form method="POST">
  Search: <input type="text" name="fname" id="sea">
  <input type="button" name="btn" onclick="showDetails()">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ignore the "Welcome to PHP" this is a trial code
the code starts after the onmouseover tag sorry for not removing it out that was part of the question

Answer (score 2):

By selecting `getElementById()` method you select the element as a whole. You can get the value of an input-element with the `value` attribute.

```
var a = document.getElementById('sea').value;
```